# How do I use the dot operator on a 2D Vector of my class while accessing a function of that class?

Tags: c++, matrix, vector

I have trouble explaining what I'm trying to do--sorry if i botched the title: so, I made a 2D Vector. The 2D Vector is an object of my class which is named Matrix. I tried doing `matrix.fill2dVector(numRows,numCols)`, and I would get these errors:

`class "std::vector<std::vector<Matrix, std::allocator<Matrix>>, std::allocator<std::vector<Matrix, std::allocator<Matrix>>>>" has no member "fill2dVector"`

`'fill2dVector': is not a member of 'std::vector<std::vector<Matrix,std::allocator<_Ty>>,std::allocator<std::vector<_Ty,std::allocator<_Ty>>>>'`

I can see that it's trying to find `fill2dVector` inside the STL vector container; but, I don't want it to do that. Also, I'm stuck using the functions in the prototypes since this is an assignment for my class, but I am allowed to modify them.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Matrix
{
public:
    Matrix();

    double& operator()(const int rn, const int cn);

    void operator()();

    void fill2dVector(int &numRows, int &numCols);

    void display2dVector(int &numRows, int &numCols) const;

private:
    int numRows = 10, numCols = 10;
    std::vector<std::vector <double>> data;
};

Matrix::Matrix()
{
    data[10][10] = {};
}

double& Matrix::operator()(const int rn, const int cn)
{
    return data[rn][cn];
}

void Matrix::operator()()
{
    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c)
        {
            data[r][c] = 0;
        }
    }
}

void Matrix::display2dVector(int &numRows, int &numCols) const
{
    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; ++r)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c)
        {
            std::cout << "   " << data[r][c] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

void Matrix::fill2dVector(int &numRows, int &numCols)
{
    for (int r = 0; r < numRows; ++r)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter " << numCols << " values for row #" << r << std::endl;
        for (int c = 0; c < numCols; ++c)
        {
            std::cin >> data[r][c];
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Enter the size of the matrix:" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "   How many rows? ";
    int numRows;
    std::cin >> numRows;

    std::cout << "How many columns? ";
    int numCols;
    std::cin >> numCols;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::cout << "*** numRows = " << numRows << ", " << "numCols = " << numCols << std::endl;

    std::vector< std::vector <Matrix> > matrix;

    std::cout << "Contents of the " << numRows << " x " << numCols << " vector:" << std::endl;
    matrix.fill2dVector(numRows,numCols);
}
```

Comment: matrix is a `std::vector`. `std::vector`s don't have methods called `fill2dVector`. Just because this `std::vector` contains another `std::vector` which contains objects that have a method called `fill2dVector` doesn't mean that the first `std::vector` must also have a method called `fill2dVector` that does the same thing. C++ does not work this way. Yes, you said "I don't want it to do that", so you need to figure out what you want to do, instead.

Comment: Note: `data[10][10] = {};` will not allocate storage. It's assigning 0 to storage you haven't allocated yet. I recommend taking a read-through of [some good `std::vector` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of :

`std::vector< std::vector <Matrix> > matrix;`

Write :

`Matrix matrix;`

Also your matrix implementation is broken because you access vector elements without allocation and while filling doesn't check for vector size so you can get into an access out of bounds and why are you passing those ints by reference ?

Comment: a lot of the code is from part 1 of the assignment where i had to use an array the private member variables were max_rows and max_cols so i needed to pass those two ints by reference to not lose them after accepting a user's chosen rows and columns; part 2 required me to use a vector--which really confused me

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if I understand your question so I think
I provide a code sample on accessing a 3d vector object I wrote
a while ago and my guess is, this will really help you solve your
Question. Just remove one layer for accessing a 2d vector.

With that Example code you should be able to solve your question.
There is also a `<random>` example referring to another question of yours.

```c++
#include <iostream>     // cout
#include <vector>       // vector
#include <random>       //rand, srand
#include <algorithm>    //shuffle
#include <string>       //using strings
#include <limits>       //cin

using my_engine = std::random_device; //most random


class deck
{
   std::string comment;

public:
   void output(std::string);    //txt output
   void display_card_deck();//display all cards
   void mix_cards();        //delete and remix deck new game

   size_t getCards(size_t playnum, size_t color, size_t number);

private:
   size_t _inp_check();     //input player number + check
   std::vector < std::vector < std::vector < size_t > > > _card_deck;           //assign 3d vector
   void _shuffle_cards(size_t players); //mix and shuffle cards randomly
};


void deck::output(std::string comment)
{
    std::cout << comment  << " cards are used for " << _card_deck.size() << std::endl;

}



int main()
{
    deck play;
    //round 1
    play.mix_cards(); //mix cards randomly and input player number 2-8
    play.output ("Welcome Player ... and Player ... "); //text, number of players

    std::cout << play.getCards(0,2,2) << "test output" << std::endl; //pick one card

    //round 2
    play.mix_cards();
    std::cout << play.getCards(0,2,2) << std::endl; //pick one card

    play.output ("Welcome Player ... and Player ... "); //text, number of players
    play.display_card_deck();

   return 0;
}


//members of deck class

size_t deck :: _inp_check()
{
    size_t input;

    while (!(std::cin >> input) || input < 2 || input > 8)
    {
         std::cin.clear();
         std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
         std::cout << "Try again and enter a valid player number from 2 to 8: "<< "\n";
    }

    return input;
}

void deck :: mix_cards()
{
    if (_card_deck.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "How many Players are playing today? (2-8):" << std::endl;
        size_t players = _inp_check();
        _shuffle_cards(players);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "How many Players are playing today? (2-8):" << std::endl;
        _card_deck.clear();
        size_t players = _inp_check();
        _shuffle_cards(players);
    }
}

void deck :: _shuffle_cards(size_t players)
{
    my_engine engn; //random_device

      for(size_t playnum = 0; playnum < players; ++playnum)
      {
            std::vector < std::vector < size_t > > d1;
            _card_deck.push_back( d1 );

            for(size_t color = 0; color < 4; color++)
                {
                std::vector < size_t > d2;
                        _card_deck[playnum].push_back( d2 );

                    for(size_t k = 1; k < 11; k++)
                    {
                        _card_deck[playnum][color].push_back( k ); //1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
                    }

                shuffle(_card_deck[playnum][color].begin(), _card_deck[playnum][color].end(), engn);
            }
      }
}

void deck :: display_card_deck()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < _card_deck.size(); i++)
    {
        for (size_t j = 0; j < _card_deck[i].size(); j++)
        {
            for (size_t k = 0; k < _card_deck[i][j].size(); k++)
            {
                std::cout << "_card_deck[" << i << "][" << j << "][" << k << "] = " << _card_deck[i][j][k] << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

size_t deck::getCards(size_t playnum, size_t color, size_t number)
{
    return  _card_deck[playnum][color][number];
}
```